# Crashlytics recordError removed?

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

Xcode 8.3.2, Swift 3, Crashlytics 3.8.5 installed

`Crashlytics.sharedInstance().recordError(error)` - says "Value of type 'Crashlytics' has no member 'recordError'".

I can't see any recordError function in Crashlytics file as well. But doc says us that it should work.

https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/logged-errors.html#logs-and-custom-keys

Comment: you need to use CLSLog I think

Comment: CLSLog helps with crashes, but I need to log non-fatal errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i have run the code under both version of Crashlytics and its working fine in Xcode 8.3.2, Swift 3,
using pod

> use_frameworks!
>
> pod 'Fabric'
>
> pod 'Crashlytics'
>
> Crashlytics :- Version 3.8.4 (121)

code is working fine

```
Crashlytics.sharedInstance().recordError(error)
```

Now i had update Crashlytics pod

> [Crashlytics] Version 3.8.5 (123))
>
> Build the Project and Run. same code working fine for me.

Comment: yep, it's very strange. I using Fabric mac app installation not via Pods. Mac app tolds me that newest version of framework is installed. I reinstall manually all frameworks and mac app - and recordError appears.

Answer (score 2):

Use this method for earlier Crashlytics versions

```
import FirebaseCrashlytics
        
//use following insted of Crashlytics.sharedInstance().recordError(error)
    
Crashlytics.crashlytics().record(error:)
```

Answer (score 0):

it has been updated to

```
Crashlytics.crashlytics().record(error: self)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import Firebase

Crashlytics.crashlytics().record(error: myError)
```